# Prestashop 1.7, display the lowest price for a product with combinations

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I am looking for a solution to display the lowest price for products with combinations. Prestashop does not provide this by default, I would have to manually set the lowest price as the default configuration. I have tried to edit the Product controller. But unfortunately it doesn't work. I would just like to have a variable, and replace it with `$product.price`.

I looked at various solutions. Here are my attempts to obtain such a solution:

```
if (!empty($product->getAttributeCombinations())) {
  $prices = array();
  foreach ($product_attrbiute_ids as $prod_id) {
    array_push($prices, $product->getPrice($tax = true, $prod_id));
  }
  sort($prices);

  $min_price = $prices[0];
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. No error - the variable is just always empty. Which controller should I make changes to? How to correctly assign it to a smarty? Maybe a completely different solution?

Comment: I know a module just for that, "Mejor precio en listados":
https://panel.wecomm.es/cart.php?gid=7

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested my code, but i think it should be something like this in the ProductController, in the assignAttributesGroups function.

I have put some NEW comments so you can easily find my edits. Let me know if it works, and don't forget to use an override.

```
protected function assignAttributesGroups($product_for_template = null)
{
    $colors = [];
    $groups = [];
    $this->combinations = [];

    /* NEW */
    $attributes_groups = $this->product->getAttributesGroups($this->context->language->id);
    if (is_array($attributes_groups) && $attributes_groups) {
        foreach ($attributes_groups as $k => $row) {
            if ($lowestPrice["lowest_price"] > (float)$row['price'] or $lowestPrice['lowest_price_id'] === null) {
                $lowestPrice["lowest_price"] = (float)$row['price'];
                $lowestPrice["lowest_price_id"] = $row['id_attribute'];
            }
        }
    }
    /* END NEW *?

    /** @todo (RM) should only get groups and not all declination ? */
    $attributes_groups = $this->product->getAttributesGroups($this->context->language->id);
    if (is_array($attributes_groups) && $attributes_groups) {
        $combination_images = $this->product->getCombinationImages($this->context->language->id);
        $combination_prices_set = [];
        foreach ($attributes_groups as $k => $row) {
            // Color management
            if (isset($row['is_color_group']) && $row['is_color_group'] && (isset($row['attribute_color']) && $row['attribute_color']) || (file_exists(_PS_COL_IMG_DIR_ . $row['id_attribute'] . '.jpg'))) {
                $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['value'] = $row['attribute_color'];
                $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['name'] = $row['attribute_name'];
                if (!isset($colors[$row['id_attribute']]['attributes_quantity'])) {
                    $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['attributes_quantity'] = 0;
                }
                $colors[$row['id_attribute']]['attributes_quantity'] += (int) $row['quantity'];
            }
            if (!isset($groups[$row['id_attribute_group']])) {
                $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']] = [
                    'group_name' => $row['group_name'],
                    'name' => $row['public_group_name'],
                    'group_type' => $row['group_type'],
                    'default' => -1,
                ];
            }

            $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes'][$row['id_attribute']] = [
                'name' => $row['attribute_name'],
                'html_color_code' => $row['attribute_color'],
                'texture' => (@filemtime(_PS_COL_IMG_DIR_ . $row['id_attribute'] . '.jpg')) ? _THEME_COL_DIR_ . $row['id_attribute'] . '.jpg' : '',
                /* new */
                #'selected' => (isset($product_for_template['attributes'][$row['id_attribute_group']]['id_attribute']) && $product_for_template['attributes'][$row['id_attribute_group']]['id_attribute'] == $row['id_attribute']) ? true : false,
                'selected'=> ($lowestPrice["lowest_price_id"] ==  $row['id_attribute']) ? true : false,
                /* END NEW */
            ];

            //$product.attributes.$id_attribute_group.id_attribute eq $id_attribute
            if ($row['default_on'] && $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['default'] == -1) {
                $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['default'] = (int) $row['id_attribute'];
            }
            if (!isset($groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes_quantity'][$row['id_attribute']])) {
                $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes_quantity'][$row['id_attribute']] = 0;
            }
            $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['attributes_quantity'][$row['id_attribute']] += (int) $row['quantity'];

            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['attributes_values'][$row['id_attribute_group']] = $row['attribute_name'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['attributes'][] = (int) $row['id_attribute'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['price'] = (float) $row['price'];

            // Call getPriceStatic in order to set $combination_specific_price
            if (!isset($combination_prices_set[(int) $row['id_product_attribute']])) {
                $combination_specific_price = null;
                Product::getPriceStatic((int) $this->product->id, false, $row['id_product_attribute'], 6, null, false, true, 1, false, null, null, null, $combination_specific_price);
                $combination_prices_set[(int) $row['id_product_attribute']] = true;
                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['specific_price'] = $combination_specific_price;
            }
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['ecotax'] = (float) $row['ecotax'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['weight'] = (float) $row['weight'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['quantity'] = (int) $row['quantity'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['reference'] = $row['reference'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['unit_impact'] = $row['unit_price_impact'];
            $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['minimal_quantity'] = $row['minimal_quantity'];
            if ($row['available_date'] != '0000-00-00' && Validate::isDate($row['available_date'])) {
                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['available_date'] = $row['available_date'];
                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['date_formatted'] = Tools::displayDate($row['available_date']);
            } else {
                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['available_date'] = $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['date_formatted'] = '';
            }

            if (!isset($combination_images[$row['id_product_attribute']][0]['id_image'])) {
                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['id_image'] = -1;
            } else {
                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['id_image'] = $id_image = (int) $combination_images[$row['id_product_attribute']][0]['id_image'];
                if ($row['default_on']) {
                    foreach ($this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['product']->value['images'] as $image) {
                        if ($image['cover'] == 1) {
                            $current_cover = $image;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!isset($current_cover)) {
                        $current_cover = array_values($this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['product']->value['images'])[0];
                    }

                    if (is_array($combination_images[$row['id_product_attribute']])) {
                        foreach ($combination_images[$row['id_product_attribute']] as $tmp) {
                            if ($tmp['id_image'] == $current_cover['id_image']) {
                                $this->combinations[$row['id_product_attribute']]['id_image'] = $id_image = (int) $tmp['id_image'];

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if ($id_image > 0) {
                        if (isset($this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['images']->value)) {
                            $product_images = $this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['images']->value;
                        }
                        if (isset($product_images) && is_array($product_images) && isset($product_images[$id_image])) {
                            $product_images[$id_image]['cover'] = 1;
                            $this->context->smarty->assign('mainImage', $product_images[$id_image]);
                            if (count($product_images)) {
                                $this->context->smarty->assign('images', $product_images);
                            }
                        }

                        $cover = $current_cover;

                        if (isset($cover) && is_array($cover) && isset($product_images) && is_array($product_images)) {
                            $product_images[$cover['id_image']]['cover'] = 0;
                            if (isset($product_images[$id_image])) {
                                $cover = $product_images[$id_image];
                            }
                            $cover['id_image'] = (Configuration::get('PS_LEGACY_IMAGES') ? ($this->product->id . '-' . $id_image) : (int) $id_image);
                            $cover['id_image_only'] = (int) $id_image;
                            $this->context->smarty->assign('cover', $cover);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* NEW */
        $groups[$row['id_attribute_group']]['default'] = (int) $lowestPrice['lowest_price_id'];
        /* END NEW */



        // wash attributes list depending on available attributes depending on selected preceding attributes
        $current_selected_attributes = [];
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($groups as &$group) {
            ++$count;
            if ($count > 1) {
                //find attributes of current group, having a possible combination with current selected
                $id_product_attributes = [0];
                $query = 'SELECT pac.`id_product_attribute`
                    FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute_combination` pac
                    INNER JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute` pa ON pa.id_product_attribute = pac.id_product_attribute
                    WHERE id_product = ' . $this->product->id . ' AND id_attribute IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $current_selected_attributes)) . ')
                    GROUP BY id_product_attribute
                    HAVING COUNT(id_product) = ' . count($current_selected_attributes);
                if ($results = Db::getInstance()->executeS($query)) {
                    foreach ($results as $row) {
                        $id_product_attributes[] = $row['id_product_attribute'];
                    }
                }
                $id_attributes = Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT `id_attribute` FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attribute_combination` pac2
                    WHERE `id_product_attribute` IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $id_product_attributes)) . ')
                    AND id_attribute NOT IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $current_selected_attributes)) . ')');
                foreach ($id_attributes as $k => $row) {
                    $id_attributes[$k] = (int) $row['id_attribute'];
                }
                foreach ($group['attributes'] as $key => $attribute) {
                    if (!in_array((int) $key, $id_attributes)) {
                        unset(
                            $group['attributes'][$key],
                            $group['attributes_quantity'][$key]
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
            //find selected attribute or first of group
            $index = 0;
            $current_selected_attribute = 0;
            foreach ($group['attributes'] as $key => $attribute) {
                if ($index === 0) {
                    $current_selected_attribute = $key;
                }
                if ($attribute['selected']) {
                    $current_selected_attribute = $key;

                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($current_selected_attribute > 0) {
                $current_selected_attributes[] = $current_selected_attribute;
            }
        }

        // wash attributes list (if some attributes are unavailables and if allowed to wash it)
        if (!Product::isAvailableWhenOutOfStock($this->product->out_of_stock) && Configuration::get('PS_DISP_UNAVAILABLE_ATTR') == 0) {
            foreach ($groups as &$group) {
                foreach ($group['attributes_quantity'] as $key => &$quantity) {
                    if ($quantity <= 0) {
                        unset($group['attributes'][$key]);
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach ($colors as $key => $color) {
                if ($color['attributes_quantity'] <= 0) {
                    unset($colors[$key]);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach ($this->combinations as $id_product_attribute => $comb) {
            $attribute_list = '';
            foreach ($comb['attributes'] as $id_attribute) {
                $attribute_list .= '\'' . (int) $id_attribute . '\',';
            }
            $attribute_list = rtrim($attribute_list, ',');
            $this->combinations[$id_product_attribute]['list'] = $attribute_list;
        }
        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'groups' => $groups,
            'colors' => (count($colors)) ? $colors : false,
            'combinations' => $this->combinations,
            'combinationImages' => $combination_images,
        ]);
    } else {
        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'groups' => [],
            'colors' => false,
            'combinations' => [],
            'combinationImages' => [],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the solution does not work. The price is not displayed at all. Additionally, cannot change the variant on the product page with variants.

Answer (score 0):

The previous solution from @Inform-all is actually not far from being correct. I have updated the piece of "NEW" code as below.

Don't forget then to pass the `$lowestPrice` variable to Smarty assign function and you will be able to retrieve the minimum amount in your template

```
$attributes_groups = $this->product->getAttributesGroups($this->context->language->id);
        if (is_array($attributes_groups) && $attributes_groups) {
            foreach ($attributes_groups as $row) {
                $price = Product::getPriceStatic($product_for_template['id_product'], false, $row['id_product_attribute']);
                if ($lowestPrice["amount"] > $price or $lowestPrice['lowest_price_id'] === null) {
                    $lowestPrice["amount"] = $price;
                    $lowestPrice["lowest_price_id"] = $row['id_attribute'];
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps someone with the same issue.